# Repeating the same window for several functions in Presto?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, trino

I'm running a query similar to the following to accumulate the sum of the amount positive values and of total events on a 7-day window by the date.

```
SELECT
    first_value(date) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS date_left,
    last_value(date) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS date_right,
    sum(positives) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS events,
    sum(events) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total
FROM
    data
```

While this query works, it's not pretty since it repeats the same long window specification 4 times.

Is there any way to "save" a window in Presto, or to use several functions on the same window?

Comment: Most databases support the standard `WINDOW` definition in the `FROM` clause.  However, Presto does not seem to support this based on the documentation:  https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html.

Comment: Also just FYI Trino (rebranded version of PrestoSQL) [supprots](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#window-clause) WINDOW definition.

Answer (score 3):

To echo what @Gordon Linoff and @Guru Stron said in the comments, PrestoDB does support window functions but does not support the `WINDOW` clause. However, Trino ([formerly PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) has [support for `WINDOW`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#window-clause), and Trino [recently added more features](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html) around this earlier this year. Such as:

- Full support for the `RANGE` frame type.
- Support for the `GROUPS` frame type.
- More support for the `WINDOW` clause.

If your team requires these types of features I recommend upgrading to Trino.